# Remove all characters after last - but only if after - has four characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string which could contain several different values, among them are.

EDITED for clarity: 
var test could equal FW21002-185 or FW21002-181-0001 or abcdefg or 245-453-654 or FW21002-181-00012

I would like to remove all characters after **and including** the last - only if that string contains four characters after the last dash. So in the above strings examples, the only one that should be changed is the second one to "FW21002-181" All others would remain as they are.

How would I do this in JavaScript. Regex is ok as well. Thanks.

Comment: The JavaScript you posted is meaningless and syntactically invalid.

Comment: It was not meant to be "valid" javascript. I was trying to state that variable test could contain any of the values shown below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regex to do this would be

```
var chopped = test.replace(/-[^-]{4,}$/, '-');
```

(assuming you want that "-" at the end). (Oh also this is intended to match 4 *or more* trailing characters - if you want exactly four, just get rid of the comma in `{4,}`.)

Comment: thanks, my mistake, I don't want the last "-". So I guess its var chopped = test.replace(/-[^\-]{4,}$/, '');

Comment: yes - also I fixed that stray backslash in the [^-] thing - you don't need that.

Comment: Worked perfect without the , in the {4} and with "" as the replace string, THX!!!

Answer (score 2):

No regex required:

```
var str = ...,
    pos = str.lastIndexOf('-');

if (pos > -1 && pos == str.length - 5)
  str = str.substring(0, pos);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a regex:

```
function removeLongSuffix(var str)
{
    var tokens = str.split('-'),
        last = tokens[tokens.length-1];
        if (last.length > 3)
        {
            return tokens.slice(0,-1).join('-');
        }
        return str;
}
```